# How to encrypt password stored in [SSIS Configurations] table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, oledb

i am facing big trouble in SSIS. For ease of deployment in production,I configured my ssis package connection string.I stored this connection string in  [SSIS Configurations] table.I use data flow task in SSIS package.Obviously source db and destination DB connection strings are stored in this  [SSIS Configurations] table.When I gave demo to client he said why you are storing password in plain text.At that time I thought of using windows authentication but both of the servers are not connected to any domain.How can I use windows authentication in this case or else is there any way to encrypt password present in   [SSIS Configurations] table.I am using SQLserver 2005.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encrypt your package with a password or userkey.

For example if you select the package properties and change the ProtectionLevel to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword then enter a password, your sensitive data such as passwords will be encrypted.

[Securing your SSIS Packages using Package Protection Level](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2091/securing-your-ssis-packages-using-package-protection-level/)

I am not aware that you can encrypt packages using Windows authentication.